# Visual Studio Professional 2017: Unable to commit changes to GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio, synchronization, commit, solution

I am attempting to commit some new files to a GitHub repository, and have run into an issue; Visual studio won't let me commit. When I Try, I get the following error:

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
error: open(".vs/SAPS/v15/Browse.VC.opendb"): Permission denied
fatal: Unable to process path .vs/SAPS/v15/Browse.VC.opendb
```

My first response was that I needed to pull first, and I was able to pull successfully. However, this didn't fix the problem in the slightest.

A quick search for similar problems yielded an issue that appears to be related:

[GitHub Commit Error: Permission denied fatal: Unable to process path ~/App_Data/aspnet-MyProject.mdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255844/github-commit-error-permission-denied-fatal-unable-to-process-path-app-data)

The problem in this issue is that the asker tried to commit mdf files. However, near as I can tell, I'm not using any such files. The files I am trying to commit are .cpp and .h files. However, Visual studio created some additional files in the solution that may be causing problems. The files Visual Studio added by itself are mostly .db and .opendb files. Frankly, I don't even know what those are, and some of them appear to exist outside of the solution I am trying to use.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me why I am unable to commit my changes, even though I am perfectly able to pull other changes. Thanks.

Comment: This image shows the file structure that is visible in the team explorer:  https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DaTBWCAVAAAezQp.jpg:large

Answer (score 1):

you should have added to ignore the whole .vs subdirectory. It is internal cache of vs

do it now, and [untrack it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057/2303202)

ps: the error happens because VS opens the file exclusively, so git cannot read it

PPS: I seem to be able to add directory to ignore just from team explorer's rightclick menu:

[image: Screenshot of ignoring directory]

or you can always create or edit the .gitignore file yourself.

Probably you will have to install [git for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) to use command-line. Though there is some git.exe deep inside vs installation, maybe you could use that one as well. Try "Action"->"Open command prompt" in the team explorer, if the git available there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm still a bit unsure what to do, as I'm not super familiar with the innermost workings of visual studio. Should I try to use gitignore from inside visual studio itself, or from the repository on github? In either case, where do I enter the command? is there a terminal I should type it in?

Comment: Added to answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .gitignore file in the repository. Inside of the file put .vs  - this will let your git software ignore any .vs file extensions, which is whats creating the permission denied.