# How to push Unity Project with Visual Studio on GitHub?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, github-actions

I want to push my unity code on GitHub but I get this error.

> '''Git failed with a fatal error. error:
>   open(".vs/Unity_Second_Game/v16/Browse.VC.opendb"): Permission denied
>   fatal: Unable to process path
>   .vs/Unity_Second_Game/v16/Browse.VC.opendb'''

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub Commit Error: Permission denied fatal: Unable to process path ~/App\_Data/aspnet-MyProject.mdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255844/github-commit-error-permission-denied-fatal-unable-to-process-path-app-data)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be including and VS files on github. [Here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore) is a link to the official .gitignore for unity.

For this specific situation, the main line of note is

```
# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/
```

You can just copy and paste the whole ignore into the root of your repo.

Comment: Thanks for helping but i restart my computer then try again push suddenly complated.

Comment: Even if it now worked you really should still add the gitignore file.

Comment: Thanks for helping I added gitignore file in my repo.

Comment: Glad to hear, you should mark this as the answer then so others with similar problems can find the solution.