# git failed with error - is a directory add files inside instead

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, git-clone

I have created new MVC project in my existing solution.
While adding these new project to existing solution, I am getting below error.

I am using VS 2019 now. Earlier, I was using VS 2017 in which everything works fine.

These issue is occurring for all directory in project. e.g. `xml/ css/jquery`.
Even though we manually add those files in folder it still showing same error.

Git failed with a fatal error.

```
error: mvctestproject/wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/: is a directory - add files inside instead
fatal: Unable to process path mvctestproject/wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if, as it [was the case here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60197423/6309):

- you have a process with a lock on a file in that folder
- you can, in Team Explorer, right-click the file and select "Ignore this local resource".

The idea is Git is not able to reach a specific file in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And solved it just removing folders that dont have projects inside

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was having complete project inside a folder B.

My structure was `git repo folder -> folder A -> folder B -> project files`.

I was getting error when I was pushing `folder B`.

So, I have moved all the files of folder B directly under folder A and deleted folder B (anyways folder B was of no use for me).

This resolved my issue.